# Scrollbar does not work in tkinter canvas widget after adding labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I have mad an app that ads label to the canvas. I have also set the vertical scrollbar. The problem is that I can not activate scrollbar, the scrollbar does not allow scrolling.
I have used `grid_propagate(0)` but it still does not work. HOw to activate this feature?
The program does not show me any error.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
frame.grid_propagate(0)

canvas=Canvas(frame,width=300,height=300)

vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky="NS")
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)

n=0
m=10
def novi():
    global n
    global m

    n +=1

    m=m+2

    e = Label(canvas, text=m )
    e.grid(row=n,column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

b = Button(root, text="add", command=novi)
b.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky="N")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ‘pack_propagate` only works if you are using `pack`

Comment: ok, do you know how can solve the problem, if Im using `grid` in my program?

Comment: You could try to look for something related to propagation on the [effbot `grid` page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)?

Comment: @fhdrsdg I have used "grid_propagate(0)" but it still does not work, I cant activate the scrollbar

Comment: Well yeah, by using `grid_propagate(0)` you remove resizing, so the widgets aren't resized. Also you really just completely changed your question. You first ask how to fix the size of your canvas, `grid_propagate(0)` does exactly that, but then it turns out that's actually not what you're trying to achieve? And now you ask about activating a scrollbar, which doesn't make sense if your widget isn't bigger than its parent. You seem to be focusing on too small questions without really telling us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want from my program to creates `label` when I click the button. The label should be in canvas, and scrollbar should alow scrolling, so that I can see all labels.

Please run the code, and you will se the problem that I have

Comment: Do you see how the question that you posted does not make clear what you actually want? You ask about one small part without enough context for us to really understand the desired behavior. Right now you might be best off deleting this question and posting a new one in which you explain what you want, what you have tried and why those tries were unsuccessful. Read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help in writing a good question.

Comment: @fhdrsdg If you run the program you will see the issue that I have. I cant scroll to see all added values. Please run the program and you will see the problem.

Comment: if you add Label/Widget to canvas then you need `canvas.create_window()`, not `grid()/pack()/place()` http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method

Comment: example code with class ScrolledFrame https://pastebin.com/zpj91XmN

Answer (score 0):

**You can try doing something like this:**

1. Indicate the scrollregion of the canvas, example:

   > canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0, 940, 1200))
2. Indicate where to put your widget inside the canvas 
    with a code similar to:

   > canvas.create_window(x, y, window=here_goes_your_widget)

   In this example 'x' and 'y' are the coordinates.

---

As far as I know you must to manually indicate the position of the widget you want to put inside your canvas.

Well, I hope this serves as a help. Hasta la próxima, che!